# postgresql install

Tags: postgresql, shell, installation

I installed PostgreSQL after I got a problem in SQL shell while running the command `\l`
[image]

I installed PostgreSQL after executing the command `\l` I encountered this error

> 'more' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne ou externe, un
> programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL did you install? Why do you use such an old version of psql? How did you start psql?

Comment: Is `more` installed on your system?  Try `\pset pager off` and see what happens.